# Fast string suffix checking in C# (.NET 4.0)?

Tags: c#, string

What is the fastest method of checking string suffixes in C#?

I need to check each string in a large list (anywhere from 5000 to 100000 items) for a particular term.  The term is guaranteed never to be embedded within the string.  In other words, if the string contains the term, it will be at the end of the string.  The string is also guaranteed to be longer than the suffix.  Cultural information is not important.

These are how different methods performed against 100000 strings (half of them have the suffix):

```
 1.  Substring Comparison - 13.60ms
 2.  String.Contains - 22.33ms
 3.  CompareInfo.IsSuffix - 24.60ms
 4.  String.EndsWith - 29.08ms
 5.  String.LastIndexOf - 30.68ms
```

These are average times.  [Edit]  Forgot to mention that the strings also get put into separate lists, but this is not important.  It does add to the running time though.

On my system substring comparison (extracting the end of the string using the String.Substring method and comparing it to the suffix term) is consistently the fastest when tested against 100000 strings.  The problem with using substring comparison though is that Garbage Collection can slow it down considerably (more than the other methods) because String.Substring creates new strings.  The effect is not as bad in .NET 4.0 as it was in 3.5 and below, but it is still noticeable.  In my tests, String.Substring performed consistently slower on sets of 12000-13000 strings.  This will obviously differ between systems and implementations.

[EDIT]
Benchmark code:
http://pastebin.com/smEtYNYN

[EDIT]
FlyingStreudel's code runs fast, but Jon Skeet's recommendation of using EndsWith in conjunction with StringComparison.Ordinal appears to be the best option.

Comment: No comment on what .NET is doing, but if you need to test the same string for many suffixes, constructing a suffix tree might be advisable: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If that's the time taken to check 100,000 strings, does it really matter?

Personally I'd use `string.EndsWith` on the grounds that it's the most descriptive: it says exactly what you're trying to test.

I'm somewhat suspicious of the fact that it appears to be performing worst though... if you could post your benchmark code, that would be very useful. (In particular, it really shouldn't have to do as much work as `string.Contains`.)

Have you tried specifying an ordinal match? That may well make it significantly faster:

```
if (x.EndsWith(y, StringComparison.Ordinal))
```

Of course, you shouldn't do that unless you *want* an ordinal comparison - are you expecting culturally-sensitive matches? (Developers tend not to consider this sort of thing, and I *very* firmly include myself in that category.)

Comment: In this case performance is an issue because of how the application is being used (it handles multiple sets of data).

Comment: @ilitirit: So what's your target speed? How fast is fast enough? 29ms for 100,000 strings sounds pretty fast to me. How often does your application need to do this?

Comment: It's actually faster than 29ms but the strings get put into different lists so that adds to the overhead.  Culture is not important because the strings are essentially machine-generated filenames.  I agree that the difference in speed isn't much over 1 iteration but this operates over multiple sets (I'm not sure how many - it depends on the time of day/month etc).  I'll have to ask the powers that be about their performance metrics.

Comment: @ilitirit: That's definitely what you should do next, yes. (And try it with StringComparison.Ordinal of course.) Have you checked that this is actually a significant bottleneck in your app first, btw?

Comment: I'm currently doing some performance digging using dotTrace. We have some huge recursive structure which causes certain 'low level' methods to be called very often (+12 000 000 times in one request).
The (http) request takes now 24 seconds (it was almost 2 minutes before). Using EndsWith in one of those methods is apparently taking 1.7 secconds. Small changes like this can add up :)
By removing some Regex.IsMatch, 1 request dropped from 1.8 to 29 seconds.
I'm going to try the StringComparison.Ordinal!

Answer (score 14):

Jon is absolutely right; this is potentially not an apples-to-apples comparison because different string methods have different defaults for culteral sensitivity. Be very sure that you are getting the comparison semantics you intend to in each one.

In addition to Jon's answer, I'd add that the relevant question is not "which is fastest?" but rather "which is too slow?"  What's your performance goal for this code? The slowest method still finds the result in less time than it takes a movie projector to advance to the next frame, and obviously that is not noticable by humans. If your goal is that the search appears instantaneous to the user then you're done; any of those methods work.  If your goal is that the search take less than a millisecond then none of those methods work; they are all orders of magnitude too slow.  *What's the budget?*

Comment: +1 for "which is too slow" nicely redirects thoughts to the budget question.

Answer (score 6):

I took a look at your benchmark code and frankly, it looks dodgy.

You are measuring all kinds of extraneous things along with what it is you want to measure; you're measuring the cost of the foreach and the adding to a list, both of which might have costs of the same order of magnitude as the thing you are attempting to test.

Also, you are not throwing out the first run; remember, the JIT compiler is going to jit the code that you call the *first* time through the loop, and it is going to be hot and ready to go the *second* time, so your results will therefore be skewed; you are averaging one potentially very large thing with many small things. In the past when I have done this I have discovered situations where the jit time actually dominated the time of everything else. Is that realistic?  Do you mean to measure the jit time, or should it be not considered as part of the average?

Answer (score 4):

I dunno how fast this is, but this is what I would do?

```
static bool HasSuffix(string check, string suffix)
{
    int offset = check.Length - suffix.Length;
    for (int i = 0; i < suffix.Length; i++)
    {
        if (check[offset + i] != suffix[i])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

edit: OOPS x2

edit: So I wrote my own little benchmark... does this count? It runs 25 trials of evaluating one million strings and takes the average of the difference in performance. The handful of times I ran it it was consistently outputting that CharCompare was faster by ~10-40ms over one million records. So that is a hugely unimportant increase in efficiency (.000000001s/call) :) All in all I doubt it will matter which method you implement.

```
class Program
{
    volatile static List<string> strings;
    static double[] results = new double[25];
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        strings = new List<string>();
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int rep = 0; rep < 25; rep++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Run " + rep);
            strings.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
            {
                string temp = "";
                for (int j = 0; j < r.Next(3, 101); j++)
                {
                    temp += Convert.ToChar(
                        Convert.ToInt32(
                        Math.Floor(26 * r.NextDouble() + 65)));
                }
                if (i % 4 == 0)
                {
                    temp += "abc";
                }
                strings.Add(temp);
            }
            OrdinalWorker ow = new OrdinalWorker(strings);
            CharWorker cw = new CharWorker(strings);
            if (rep % 2 == 0)
            {
                cw.Run();
                ow.Run();
            }
            else
            {
                ow.Run();
                cw.Run();                    
            }
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            results[rep] = ow.finish.Subtract(cw.finish).Milliseconds;
        }
        double tDiff = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
        {
            tDiff += results[i];
        }
        double average = tDiff / 25;
        if (average < 0)
        {
            average = average * -1;
            Console.WriteLine("Char compare faster by {0}ms average", 
                average.ToString().Substring(0, 4));
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("EndsWith faster by {0}ms average", 
                average.ToString().Substring(0, 4));
        }

    }
}   



class OrdinalWorker
{
    List<string> list;
    int count;
    public Thread t;
    public DateTime finish;
    public OrdinalWorker(List<string> l)
    {
        list = l;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        t = new Thread(() => {
            string suffix = "abc";
            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                count = (list[i].EndsWith(suffix, StringComparison.Ordinal)) ? 
                    count + 1 : count;
            }
            finish = DateTime.Now;
        });
        t.Start();
    }
}

class CharWorker 
{
    List<string> list;
    int count;
    public Thread t;
    public DateTime finish;
    public CharWorker(List<string> l)
    {
        list = l;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        t = new Thread(() =>
        {
            string suffix = "abc";
            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                count = (HasSuffix(list[i], suffix)) ? count + 1 : count;
            }
            finish = DateTime.Now;
        });
        t.Start();
    }

    static bool HasSuffix(string check, string suffix)
    {
        int offset = check.Length - suffix.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < suffix.Length; i++)
        {
            if (check[offset + i] != suffix[i])
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be interesting to see if the optimizer eliminates the out-of-bounds checks on the two string accesses.

Comment: I would be amazed if the built-in implementation of `EndsWith` didn't look very similar to this, although I suspect that it's probably `extern`-ed and/or `unsafe` (and probably slightly hamstrung by culture-awareness etc too).

Comment: Er so I guess this is assuming a string to be checked is never shorter than the suffix? Thats kind of redundant considering a string shorter than the suffix could never contain the suffix.

Comment: Very fast indeed.  I'll add a link to your code to the original post.

Comment: @LukeH: With this level of micro-optimization, just the act of grabbing CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.CompareInfo.IsSuffix might cost enough to be noticeable to the OP.  Even `nativeIsSuffix` cares about things like LCID and `CompareOptions`.  In short, there is rather a lot of indirection involved when using `String.EndsWith`, possibly enough for the price to be noticeable to the op.  Though it's also possible that the jitter is able to completely blast through most or all of that indirection.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try direct access ?
I mean, you can make a loop watching for similar string, it could be faster than make a substring and having the same behaviour.

```
int i,j;
foreach(String testing in lists){
   i=0;
   j=0;
   int ok=1;
   while(ok){
      i = testing.lenght - PATTERN.lenght;
      if(i>0 && i<testing.lenght && testing[i] != PATTERN[j])
        ok = 0;
      i++;
      j++;
   }
   if(ok) return testing;
}
```

Moreover if it's big strings, you could try using hashs.

Comment: This usually is a really bad idea. You should always use Framework routines for string searching, or you suffer a risk of getting into trouble because of Unicode oddities (character combining, etc). Unless, of course, 1) Speed is more important than accuracy, and 2) You will only ever work with english characters.

Comment: The idea of using hashes is not that likely to help; generating hashes requires reading the entire string.  Comparing hashes requires reading only as many characters as necessary to discover there is no match.

Comment: by hashes, i means hashes on the substrings. But after thinking it's clearly a bad way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't profess to be an expert in this area, however I felt compelled to at least profile this to some extent (knowing full well that my fictitious scenario will differ substantially from your own) and here is what I came up with:

It seems, at least for me, `EndsWith` takes the lead with `LastIndexOf` consistently coming in second, some timings are:

```
SubString:    00:00:00.0191877
Contains:     00:00:00.0201980
CompareInfo:  00:00:00.0255181
EndsWith:     00:00:00.0120296
LastIndexOf:  00:00:00.0133181
```

These were gleaned from processing 100,000 strings where the desired suffix appeared in *all* strings and so to me simply echoes Jon's answer (where the benefit is both speed and descriptiveness). And the code used to come to these results:

```
class Program
{
    class Profiler
    {
        private Stopwatch Stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

        public TimeSpan Elapsed { get { return Stopwatch.Elapsed; } }

        public void Start()
        {
            Reset();
            Stopwatch.Start();
        }

        public void Stop()
        {            
            Stopwatch.Stop();
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            Stopwatch.Reset();
        }
    }

    static string suffix = "_sfx";
    static Profiler profiler = new Profiler();
    static List<string> input = new List<string>();
    static List<string> output = new List<string>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GenerateSuffixedStrings();

        FindStringsWithSuffix_UsingSubString(input, suffix);
        Console.WriteLine("SubString:    {0}", profiler.Elapsed);

        FindStringsWithSuffix_UsingContains(input, suffix);
        Console.WriteLine("Contains:     {0}", profiler.Elapsed);

        FindStringsWithSuffix_UsingCompareInfo(input, suffix);
        Console.WriteLine("CompareInfo:  {0}", profiler.Elapsed);

        FindStringsWithSuffix_UsingEndsWith(input, suffix);
        Console.WriteLine("EndsWith:     {0}", profiler.Elapsed);

        FindStringsWithSuffix_UsingLastIndexOf(input, suffix);
        Console.WriteLine("LastIndexOf:  {0}", profiler.Elapsed);

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void GenerateSuffixedStrings()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            input.Add(Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + suffix);
        }
    }

    static void FindStringsWithSuffix_UsingSubString(IEnumerable<string> strings, string suffix)
    {
        output.Clear();
        profiler.Start();
        foreach (var s in strings)
        {
            if(s.Substring(s.Length - 4) == suffix)
                output.Add(s);
        }
        profiler.Stop();
    }

    static void FindStringsWithSuffix_UsingContains(IEnumerable<string> strings, string suffix)
    {
        output.Clear();
        profiler.Start();
        foreach (var s in strings)
        {
            if (s.Contains(suffix))
                output.Add(s);
        }
        profiler.Stop();
    }

    static void FindStringsWithSuffix_UsingCompareInfo(IEnumerable<string> strings, string suffix)
    {
        var ci = CompareInfo.GetCompareInfo("en-GB");
        output.Clear();
        profiler.Start();
        foreach (var s in strings)
        {
            if (ci.IsSuffix(s, suffix))
                output.Add(s);
        }
        profiler.Stop();
    }

    static void FindStringsWithSuffix_UsingEndsWith(IEnumerable<string> strings, string suffix)
    {
        output.Clear();
        profiler.Start();
        foreach (var s in strings)
        {
            if (s.EndsWith(suffix))
                output.Add(s);
        }
        profiler.Stop();
    }

    static void FindStringsWithSuffix_UsingLastIndexOf(IEnumerable<string> strings, string suffix)
    {
        output.Clear();
        profiler.Start();
        foreach (var s in strings)
        {
            if (s.LastIndexOf(suffix) == s.Length - 4)
                output.Add(s);
        }
        profiler.Stop();
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

As commented, I attempted this again with only some of the strings having a suffix applied and these are the results:

```
SubString:    00:00:00.0079731
Contains:     00:00:00.0243696
CompareInfo:  00:00:00.0334056
EndsWith:     00:00:00.0196668
LastIndexOf:  00:00:00.0229599
```

The string generator method was updated as follows, to produce the strings:

```
    static void GenerateSuffixedStrings()
    {
        var nxt = false;
        var rnd = new Random();            
        for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            input.Add(Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + 
                (rnd.Next(0, 2) == 0 ? suffix : string.Empty));
        }
    }
```

Further, this trend continues if *none* of the string have a suffix:

```
SubString:    00:00:00.0055584
Contains:     00:00:00.0187089
CompareInfo:  00:00:00.0228983
EndsWith:     00:00:00.0114227
LastIndexOf:  00:00:00.0199328
```

However, this gap shortens again when assigning a quarter of the inputs a suffix (the first quarter, then sorting to `randomise` the coverage):

```
SubString:    00:00:00.0302997
Contains:     00:00:00.0305685
CompareInfo:  00:00:00.0306335
EndsWith:     00:00:00.0351229
LastIndexOf:  00:00:00.0322899
```

Conclusion? IMO, and agreeing with Jon, `EndsWith` seems the way to go (based on this limited test, anyway).

**Further Edit:**

To cure Jon's curiosity I ran a few more tests on `EndsWith`, with and without `Ordinal` string comparison...

On 100,000 strings with a quarter of them suffixed:

```
EndsWith:            00:00:00.0795617
OrdinalEndsWith:     00:00:00.0240631
```

On 1,000,000 strings with a quarter of them suffixed:

```
EndsWith:            00:00:00.5460591
OrdinalEndsWith:     00:00:00.2807860
```

On 10,000,000 strings with a quarter of them suffixed:

```
EndsWith:            00:00:07.5889581
OrdinalEndsWith:     00:00:03.3248628
```

*Note that I only ran the last test once as generating the strings proved this laptop is in need of a replacement*

Comment: All your strings have suffixes.  When I change the code to only give half of them suffixes I get similar results to what I posted on my home machine (not at work right now).

Comment: Correct, as I explained. I attempted this again with suffixes applied `randomly` and drew very similar conclusions - the biggest difference being, as you mentioned, `SubString` consistently coming out on top. I would still have to agree with Jon for the other reason though, even if not speed.

Comment: What happens if you use `s.EndsWith(suffix, StringComparison.Ordinal)`?

Answer (score -1):

There's a lot of good information here.  I wanted to note that if your suffix is short, it could be even faster to look at the last few characters individually.  My modified version of the benchmark code in question is here:  http://pastebin.com/6nNdbEvW.  It gives theses results:

1. Last char equality:  1.52 ms (50000)
2. Last 2 char equality:  1.56 ms (50000)
3. EndsWith using StringComparison.Ordinal:  3.75 ms (50000)
4. Contains:  11.10 ms (50000)
5. LastIndexOf:  14.85 ms (50000)
6. IsSuffix:  11.30 ms (50000)
7. Substring compare:  17.69 ms (50000)